# How to Translate string in array of objects with using react-i18next Without a functional component of a react

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

```
export const sentTableColumns = [
    {
        header: "Created",
        accessor: "time",
        width: 200,         
    },
    {
        header: "Type",
        accessor: "type",
        width: 270
    },
    {
        header: "Subject",
        accessor: "subject",
        width: 270
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with usetranslate? Something like that:

```
header:t("Created")
```

Or I have to work differently in a situation like this?

Comment: That would work, though it's probably more efficient to just translate it where it's rendered, provided you have all the applicable keys in your translation file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the t function or the i18next instance from outside of a React component you can simply import your ./i18n.js and use the exported i18next instance:

```
import i18next from './i18n'

i18next.t('my.key')
```

https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start
[image]

fyi: if you are lazy loading the translations, you may prefer to translate where the rendering happens... there mechanism that make sure the translations are loaded before accessing the t function, like: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense